# Hiding the title of an actionbar doesn't work on older versions of Android (using ActionBarSherlock)

Tags: android, tabs, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I am trying to hide the title part of my actionbar using ActionBarSherlock like in the second picture:
[image]

Setting:

```
actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
```

works for versions >3.0 but doesn't work on older versions. A black space remains over the tab bar.

Is there a workaround to solve that issue?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This feature is only available in ActionBarSherlock 4.0 which is currently in beta stage. You can find a link to the betas on [actionbarsherlock.com](http://actionbarsherlock.com).

There is a demo for precisely what you are trying to accomplish in the samples for 4.0.

```
public class TabNavigationCollapsed extends SherlockActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener {
    @Override protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ActionBar ab = getSupportActionBar();

        //The following two options trigger the collapsing of the main action bar view.
        ab.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
        ab.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

        ab.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
        ab.addTab(ab.newTab().setText("Tab 1").setTabListener(this));
        ab.addTab(ab.newTab().setText("Tab 2").setTabListener(this));
        ab.addTab(ab.newTab().setText("Tab 3").setTabListener(this));
    }

    @Override public void onTabReselected(Tab tab) {}
    @Override public void onTabSelected(Tab tab) {}
    @Override public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab) {}
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jake! I'm gonna try that right now! How stable is this beta version?

Comment: The latest one (last night) is pretty stable and feature complete. There appears to be a small bug with `FragmentActivity` and action items but I'll have that fixed rather quickly. It's very close to a stage where I can start considering releasing the final 4.0. Another week or two at most of development and it'll be there.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this, it worked for me

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= 10) {
        setTheme(R.style.Theme_Mo);
    }
```

or

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, 
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

Hope that this helps

Comment: What's your Theme_Mo? That doesn't exist in any sdk. The second command just hides the status bar. That's not what I'm looking for.